# How to write into Crm 2011 Entity from Sharepoint Web part

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to build a Web part that takes data from Ui and write them into a Crm 2011 entity.

Does anybody know if is it even possible and by which ways?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at using BCS:
[Connecting SharePoint Online and CRM Online using BCS - 2013 Edition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishr/archive/2013/05/13/connecting-sharepoint-online-and-crm-online-using-bcs-2013-edition.aspx)

Still not really seamless because you still need an intermediary application. The example only shows pulling CRM data into SharePoint but I believe it is supposed to be able to push data back as well.